# How to prevent back space from moving to previous page in firefox?

Tags: backspace

It's a very annoying feature.

Say I am typing a long article. Then I saw a typo. I press backspace.

Instead of eliminating the typo I go back to previous page.

And it works, for all I know, randomly. Sometimes it works as intended, namely deleting an article.

Sometimes it goes back to previous page.

Actually is there a short cut or something that makes backspace go to previous button? Under what condition? When I am not in a text box or what?

And well, how do I disable it.

Answer (score 1):

The page navigation action shouldn't trigger if a text box is active, but if you want to disable the feature altogether set `browser.backspace_action` in `about:config` to `2`.